# Declaring a HTML link in Laravel Controller

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a function that replaces certain tags in an email body that the user can generate. In the function I have an array defined that contains the tags as keys and the wanted value as value:

```
$mailVars = array(
    '[fullname]'      => $user->fullname,
    '[first_name]'    => ($user->fullname) ? ' '.strtok($user->fullname, ' ') : '',
    '[email]'         => $user->email,
    '[username]'      => $user->email,
    '[activation_url]'=> $user->confirmation_code ? route('confirm.registration', [$user->confirmation_code, $user->email]) : "#"
);
```

What I would like is the [activation_url] to be an link. Because now it leave a unpleasant long looking string that needs to be copy-pasted. What I have tried:

```
'<a href="'.$user->confirmation_code ? route('confirm.registration', [$user->confirmation_code, $user->email]) : "#".'"> Link </a>' // just doesn't work at all... nothing of the link elements is seen in the email nor a link.
```

Also tried using a `HTML::linkaction` but this returns an array and string was expected error is thrown.

Comment: What happens if you put dummy data? `'[activation_url]'=> "hi"` . Does this show up?

Comment: I changed it to `'[activation_url]' => 'please'` and then the email showed the 'please' text without the link!

Comment: `strval(HTML::linkaction(...))` might work

Comment: From the time "please" showed up that means something is wrong probably with the single and double quoting.. you could try first creating the `link`, then the `href` and then `['activation_url'] = $href`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap ternary operator in `(` and `)` for correct precedence of operators, see this snippet for comparison: https://3v4l.org/DUM5t

Comment: Changed my code and now it's working! Thank you so much :-D